# Named query with a Pageable parameter

Tags: pagination, spring-data-jpa, named-query, pageable

[LOG.warn("Finder method {} is backed by a NamedQuery but contains a Pageable parameter! Sorting delivered this Pageable will not be applied!", method)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/NamedQuery.java)

I'm getting the warning above. What is the reason of the warn?